# After running "virtualenv --python=python3.6 env" --> "-bash: virtualenv: command not found"

Tags: python-3.x, macos

После выполнения данной команды:

```
virtualenv --python=python3.6 env
```

Я получаю такое сообщение

> -bash: virtualenv: command not found

Я установил *virtualenv* следующей командой:

```
brew install pyenv-virtualenv
```

Не могли бы вы помочь мне разобраться?

Comment: По теме: Что смотрели еще? через pip пробовали установить **virtualenv** -> _pip install virtualenv_?

Comment: Скорее всего надо перегрузить терминал. (закрыть/открыть)

Comment: sudo pip install virtualenv -- this was fix my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov напишите ответ, в таком случае большее количество людей сможет воспользоваться Вашими знаниями.

Comment: @hedgehogues, "sudo pip install virtualenv" command has fixed my problem, thanks.

Comment: @hedgehogues, написал ответ. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Мне помогла решить проблему следующая команда в Терминале:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Спасибо за помощь в комментариях.